# Can one X client have multiple window?

Tags: xorg

I would like to understand `X Window System` and its terminology. So I have several question:

1. Can one `X client` have mutiple window? I think that it can but I am not sure.
2. What is relation between proces and `X cient`:
   a) Can one process have multiple `X clients`? In another word, can multiple clinet work in one process?
   b) Is possible that one `X client` work in multiple process? (I think that it is impossible and It question is stupid)
3. There are application which allow to deattach window from it. What determines if this deattached window has the same or new X client? What determines if this deattached window opertes in new or in the same proces? I think that both depend on application and are independent from X Window System. E.g. firefox allows to open tab in new window. I checked that there is still one firefox process so both windows opearte in one process. Are both windows ordered by one X client?